# Replacing an IP address with sed results in: sed: -e expression #1, char 57: Unmatched ( or \(

Tags: sed, scripting

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.)\(.*\)/ANONYMOUS\2/p' $IPLOG
```

I am trying to replace ip addr from $IPLOG to ANONYMOUS but I am getting this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 57: Unmatched ( or \(
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a backslash before one of the `)`s. You probably meant `g` (globally replace; every occurrence) instead of `p` (print if the substitution was successful, which would cause the substituted lines to be printed twice). And `\{1,\}` (or `\+` with some implementations) instead of `*` (*one or more* instead of *zero or more*):

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}/ANONYMOUS/g' < "$IPLOG"
```

Or factorized a bit:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,\}/ANONYMOUS/g' < "$IPLOG"
```

Some `sed` implementations have `-E` (or `-r` like in `ssed` or older versions of GNU `sed`) for extended regular expressions that can make it a bit more legible:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/ANONYMOUS/g' < "$IPLOG"
```

Comment: Great, Thank you so much. It's working now.